# partial constraint EXCLUDE USING gist

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have the following constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlap EXCLUDE USING gist (
    product_id WITH =,
    applicable_period WITH &&
  )
```

Now I realized, that this should only be checked conditionally, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlap EXCLUDE USING gist (
    product_id WITH =,
    applicable_period WITH &&
  )
  WHERE my_table.user_id IS NULL
```

Is this possible and otherwise how can I achieve this in an efficient/advised way? (I could add a trigger, but I hope there is more elegant/efficient approaches).

Should I resort to table partition?
Thank you

Comment: Exclusion constraints prevent 2 rows from having overlapping values - you declare a list of comparisons and at least one of them should evaluate to FALSE or NULL. So you could simply add `user_id WITH =` to your constraint definition.

Comment: but wouldn't it be "broken" because `NULL` is not equal to `NULL`?

Comment: @IVOGELOV that would indeed allow overlapping ranges for rows without a user_id. But it would also allow overlapping ranges for different users - which the filtered version wouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE), you simply need parentheses:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlap 
  EXCLUDE USING gist (product_id WITH =, applicable_period WITH &&)
WHERE (user_id is null);
```